# How do I get a CSL Usb Modem U1-TF to work?

Tags: 10.10, modem-manager

how can i connect to internet using CSL USB Modem U1-TF ? I have no problems with Huawei E550 but i can't connect using CSL U1-TF .

Fixed - Automatically available when plug in and is supported in Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: You should create an answer that says something "this just works when you plug it in" and accept it as an answer so this shows up as an answered question (instead of editing the topic) Thanks!

Comment: ^ came in here to say that good catch @Jorge

Comment: sorry bout that

Answer (score 2):

This just works when you plug it in.

Comment: credited to Jorge Castro